# Change text of button once clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to change the text of the button once clicked but it doesn't work in one snippet where as it does in the other.

Can someone help me understand what I am missing in my code?

So the first one works but in the second code, the button text doesn't change on clicking on the button. Please help me. 
I have attached both the code snippets.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fold").click(function () {
        $("#fold_p").fadeOut(function () {
            $("#fold_p").text(($("#fold_p").text() == 'Hide') ? 'Show' : 'Hide').fadeIn();
        })
    })
});
```

```css
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f4511e;
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
}

.button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="fold">
    <button class="button button1">
        <span id="fold_p">Hide</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fold").click(function () {
        $("#fold_p").fadeOut(function () {
            $("#fold_p").text(($("#fold_p").text() == 'Hide ') ? 'Show' : 'Hide').fadeIn();
        })
    })
});
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  <div id="fold">
    <span id="fold_p">Hide</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you toggle the JavaScript console (with F12), you will see that you got an error in the second fiddle which is :

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

This means that jQuery is not imported in the second fiddle as `$` variable

EDIT 2 : To summuraize, I moved the click event to the button, and I fixed the inline if by removing the trailing space in the 'Hide ' string.

EDIT 1 : It seems there was an issue too with your js code, this one in this snippet is fixing it :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#fold_p").fadeOut(function () {                  
            $("#fold_p").text(($("#fold_p").text() == 'Hide') ? 'Show' : 'Hide').fadeIn();
        })
    })
});
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button">
  <div id="fold">
    <span id="fold_p">Hide</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Umm I still see the text not changing on click

Comment: @AakankshaChoudhary I have added a snippet, tell me if it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Just for clarity, he moved the `click` event to the `button`, and he fixed the inline if by removing the trailing space in the 'Hide ' string `$("#fold_p").text() == 'Hide '`.

Comment: Also, as an aside, it can be good to keep in mind that every time you do `$('selector')` it is actually running a function to find the element in the DOM. So it's much better if you know you're going to be using the same element several times to do `var foldP = $('#fold_p');` and then use the variable from that point forward.

Comment: Yess! @PierreCapo Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for explaining me. Sorry this is the first time I am working on WebDev so I have a lot of doubts and thanks! `var foldP = $('#fold_p');` is a good idea! @David784

Comment: @PierreCapo - you should add the explanations that David784 gave to your answer, so the full answer does not depend on reading the comments too.

Comment: You are right, that's better, I've edited my post and explained the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your java script:

```
 $("#fold_p").text(($("#fold_p").text() == 'Hide ') ? 'Show' : 'Hide').fadeIn();//note the space after 'Hide '
```

should be:

```
 $("#fold_p").text(($("#fold_p").text() == 'Hide') ? 'Show' : 'Hide').fadeIn();//no space after 'Hide'
```

Comment: Note:  I could not get this to run in fiddle, prob. due to js error noted above by Pierre Capo.  But when I run this code locally, it worked for me.  This was the only change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fold").click(function () {        
        $("#fold_p").fadeOut(function () {
           var btn_text= '';
           if($("#fold_p").text() == 'Hide'){
              btn_text = 'Show';
           }else{
              btn_text = 'Hide';
           }        
           $("#fold_p").text(btn_text).fadeIn();
        })
    })
});
```

```css
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f4511e;
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
}

.button1 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fold">
    <button class="button button1">
        <span id="fold_p">Hide</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: So the first code works anyway, the second one doesnt @mscdeveloper

Comment: Yeah I mean my first code did give hide and show but the second one didnt @mscdeveloper